# Dereference self in C function with ARC, reference passed as intptr_t

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I've got some Objective-C code that needs to work with a C function. The "UserData" of the function is of type `long`. I need to use that to pass a reference to `self`, so I pass it like so:

```
Proc((intptr_t) self);
```

The clean solution on the other end would look like this:

```
int Proc(long UserData) {
    MyType *refToSelf = (MyType*)(intptr_t)UserData;
}
```

But that's not allowed under ARC: **"Cast of 'intptr_t' (aka 'long') to 'MyType *' is disallowed with ARC"**

The C function is declared inside of `MyType`'s implementation, so I have no need to retain it. How can I get my reference in and out of a `long` with ARC?

Comment: Why do you think that casting it to `void**` is the right thing? If self is just a pointer, cast it to that pointer type. And then, more a nitpick, `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer type, `long` is a signed type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the question what you have or what you've tried, so here is a trivial sample which works and maybe you can figure out your issue from it:

```
@interface Basic : NSObject

- (void) identify;

@end

@implementation Basic

- (void) identify
{
   NSLog(@"Basic instance: %p", self);
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

void cFunction(long UserData)
{
   Basic *bp = (__bridge Basic *)(void *)UserData; // cast to void * then bridge without
                                                   // transferring ownership to the ARC world 
   [bp identify];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   NSAssert(sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *), @"can't work, sizes don't match");

   Basic *b = [Basic new];
   cFunction((long)(__bridge void *)b); // bridge to the C world without retaining
                                        // or transferring ownership then cast as long
   [b identify];
}

@end
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us everything, but normally if `MyType*` is the type of `self` you should just do

```
Proc((intptr_t)self);
```

and

```
MyType *refToSelf = (MyType*)(intptr_t)UserData;
```

Comment: That's where I started out, but then I get this error: `Cast of 'intptr_t' (aka 'long') to 'MyType *' is disallowed with ARC`

Comment: The only way around it is to use a global variable that temporarily refers to `self`, which is messy and could cause threading issues.